# Azure Data Factory - REST Pagination rules

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to pull data from Hubspot to my SQL Server Database through an Azure Data Factory pipeline with the usage of a REST dataset. I have problems setting up the right pagination rules. I've already spent a day on Google and MS guides, but I find it hard to get it working properly.

[This](https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/contacts/get_contacts) is the source API. I am able to connect and pull the first set of 20 rows. It gives an offset which is usable with `vidoffset=` which is returned in the body.

I need to return the result of vid-offset from the body to the HTTP request. Also the process needs to stop when `has-more` results in 'false'.

[image: These are my dataset connection details]

[image: These are my copy source settings]

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and I got the below results:**

First I create a linked service with this URL: `https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/lists/all/contacts/all?hapikey=demo&vidOffset`

[image]

Then after I created the pagination `end condition rule` with `$.has-more` and `absolute URL.`
For demo purpose, I took sink as a storage account.

[image]

The pipeline run success full look at the below image for reference.

[image]

[image]

For more information refer this [Ms Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support)

Comment: Hi SaiVasmi, thanks for your response. I'm able to reproduce the script you post, but this is not my solution as it only returns the first 20 rows of data. I need the "QueryParameters" function to work. Where as the relative URL is "contacts/v1/lists/all/contacts/all?hapikey=demo&vidOffset={offset}" and I use the offset from the body. But I cant get it to work.